# Compare subnodes in XMLUnit 2 - Expected child 'node2' but was 'null'

Tags: xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I need to compare XML files using `XMLUnit 2` where xml subnodes can differ in order. Due to the underlying libraries that are used I can't influence order of subnodes.

For comparison I am using:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-02</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-matchers</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-02</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The problem boils down to this JUnit test:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.xmlunit.builder.Input.fromString;
import static org.xmlunit.diff.ElementSelectors.byName;
import static org.xmlunit.matchers.CompareMatcher.isSimilarTo;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.xmlunit.diff.DefaultNodeMatcher;

import java.io.IOException;

public class XmlTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String t1 = fromClassPath("t1.xml");
        String t2 = fromClassPath("t2.xml");
        assertThat(fromString(t1), isSimilarTo(fromString(t2)).withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(byName)));
    }

    private static String fromClassPath(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return IOUtils.toString(new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream());
    }
}
```

where `t1.xml` contains:

```xml
<root>
    <child>
        <node1/>
    </child>
    <child>
        <node2/>
    </child>
</root>
```

and `t2.xml` contains:

```xml
<root>
    <child>
        <node2/>
    </child>
    <child>
        <node1/>                                                                                                                        
    </child>
</root>
```

Actually, `node1` and `node2` are changed in order. The test result is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: Expected child 'node2' but was 'null' - comparing <node2...> at /root[1]/child[1]/node2[1] to <NULL>:
<node2/>
     but: result was: 
<NULL>
```

I'm wonder if it is possible to compare such xml files with `XMLUnit 2`.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tell XMLUnit to match elements by name with no additional conditions. In your case this means the `child` elements are compared in order. You obviously need a different strategy, one that looks at the first child node of the nodes when deciding which `child` node to select as "partner" for any given `child`.

One option would be

```java
    new DefaultNodeMatcher(byXPath("./*[1]", byName), byName))
```

which would match nodes first by trying to match their first children and - if that fails to bring up any candidate - use the name of the elements themselves.

Depending on the structure of your real documents, this may be too naive and you need to use a conditional element selector

```java
    new DefaultNodeMatcher(selectorForElementNamed("child", byXPath("./*[1]", byName)), byName))
```

*Note*: the above code doesn't work with XMLUnit 2.0.0-alpha-02 because of [issue #39](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/39) - you'd have to use an XPath of `"./child/*[1]"` instead.  The `byXPath` `ElementSelector` has been fixed afterwards.

If you don't want to use XPath, you can code an `ElementSelector` yourself

```java
public static class FirstChildElementNameSelector implements ElementSelector {
    @Override
    public boolean canBeCompared(Element controlElement,
                                 Element testElement) {
        return byName.canBeCompared(firstChildElement(controlElement),
                                    firstChildElement(testElement));
    }

    private Element firstChildElement(Element e) {
        NodeList nl = e.getChildNodes();
        int len = nl.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (nl.item(i) instanceof Element) {
                return (Element) nl.item(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```java
    new DefaultNodeMatcher(selectorForElementNamed("child", new FirstChildElementNameSelector()), byName))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work either. I still get the same failure. I debugged into XMLUnit to see what's going on. I tried a different node matcher `or(selectorForElementNamed("node2", byXPath("./../*/node2", byName)), byName)` for `node2` and vice versa for `node1` but still no success.

Comment: You are correct @ksokol for two reasons.  `byXPath` doesn't work the way I intended it to https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/39 and `or` is not the correct choice.  https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/commit/50e4aeab4beebd1e8d31b9409b9b1a57cf434c46 contains two passing tests for you, the one labeled 02 will not work with aplha-03 or 2.0.0 (whatever comes next) as I intend to make the original XPath expression work.  I'll edit the answer once I've fixed the XPath issue.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer. I debugged further through XMLUnit and had the idea of a custom `NodeMatcher`. Your edited answer guided me to the right solution. For the moment I will use `FirstChildElementNameSelector`. As soon as alpha-03 is available in Maven central I will try `byXPath` `ElementSelector`. Thank you!

Comment: @ksokol I've published XMLUnit 2.0.0-alpha-03 today.

Comment: @/stefan-bodewig Thank you. It is working like intended now.